# Could a malicious Android Maven Central dependency infect the compiling host PC?

Tags: java, android-studio, maven, gradle, maven-central

AFAIK many packages on Maven Central come from github and [malware on github is not that uncommon](https://www.developer-tech.com/news/2024/feb/29/github-suffers-over-100k-infected-repos). Also everyone can upload packages to Maven Central.

My question is if a dependency could be dangerous for me when compiling only?

For example I don't know if Maven POM files can contain malicious build commands.

Also I don't know if the java compiler will run some part of the code at compile time.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: 1) You should reread that article again - the original repos are not infected, there are infected forks, and people are tricked into cloning those infected forks, **not** the original repos. 2) `many packages on maven central come from github` - the artefacts 'come' from the original repos. 3) `everyone can upload packages to maven central` - yes, but you have to register the namespace, meaning I can't start uploading infected artefacts in `org.springframework`, spring's namespace, to trick people into downlloading them, instead of the original ones.